# FSharp.Charting shows separated window for each Chart in interactive mode

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, fsharpchart

When I try to evaluate the following code in F# interactive console I get three separated chart windows (one for chartA, one for chartB and one for combined chart). How to prevent of displaying chart every time it's created? I want to display only the combined chart in single chart window.

```
let chartA = setA |> Chart.Point |> Chart.WithSeries.Style(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
let chartB = setB |> Chart.Point |> Chart.WithSeries.Style(System.Drawing.Color.Gold)
let chartC = Chart.Combine [|chartA; chartB|]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use scope

```
let chartC = 
    let chartA = setA |> Chart.Point |> Chart.WithSeries.Style(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
    let chartB = setB |> Chart.Point |> Chart.WithSeries.Style(System.Drawing.Color.Gold)
    Chart.Combine [|chartA; chartB|]
```

Or without the locals

```
let chartC (setA:seq<float*float>) (setB:seq<float*float>) = 
    [| setA |> Chart.Point |> Chart.WithSeries.Style(System.Drawing.Color.Orange) ;
       setB |> Chart.Point |> Chart.WithSeries.Style(System.Drawing.Color.Gold) |]
    |> Chart.Combine
```

Comment: It seems to work. Could you provide explanation why these approaches do the trick?

Comment: @cezarypiatek With your approach each line gets evaluated separately in F# Interactive, generating a `Chart` for each. In my approach the entire block following the `let` is evaluated at once and only the result gets plotted.